# Dynamically Get Integer for Array

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a variable dayNumHold that is holding the integer representation of the day of the week from the .getDay() function.

How do I use this variable to reference a position in another array, for example, where hours = ["7:00pm - 2:00pm", "2:00pm - 12:00am", ...]:

```
        <ion-icon item-left name="pricetag"></ion-icon>
            <h3>Today's Bar Hours</h3>
            <ion-note item-right>{{hours[{{dayNumHold}}]}}</ion-note>
        </ion-item>
```

Comment: Remove the `{{}}` around `dayNumHold` and it should work: `{{hours[dayNumHold]}}`

Comment: template interpolation only needs to happen once. {{hours[dayNumHold]}}

Comment: @user184994 Yep. Perfect. If you want to post that as the answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{hours[{{dayNumHold}}]}}` that block is incorrect, remember your interpolating that entire line not individually. template interpolation only needs to happen once. `{{hours[dayNumHold]}}`.